# Generating random string using concatenation

Tags: sas

I want to generate a random string with length 10 and I don't understand why my code doesn't work:

```
data b;
s=byte(0);
        do j=1 to 10;
            z=byte(97+floor(26*ranuni(0)));
            s=cat(s,z);
        end;
run;
```

When I ran this code line by line I discovered that the problem lies here:

```
    s=cat(s,z);
```

It doesn't change the variable s. Why is that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom's proposed fix doesn't seem to work for me - I end up with `s` being all blanks. The following alternatives behave as expected:

```
data b;
  length s s2 s3 $10 z $1;
  do j=1 to 10;
    z=byte(97+floor(26*ranuni(0)));
    s=cat(s,z); *original approach - doesn't seem to work;
    call cats(s2,z); * Alternative 1;
    substr(s3,j) = z; * Alternative 2;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because you created a variable that is only one character long. SAS will define the variable the first time that it sees it used. In your case in this statement.

```
s=byte(0);
```

Since the compiler knows that the `BYTE()` function returns a string of length 1 it defines S as a character variable of length 1.  Also why would you want to store a binary zero in a character variable?

You need to use `CATS()` function and not `CAT()` function. Otherwise S will never change since there is no room to add any more characters to the end of it.

Try something like this:

```
data b;
  length s $10 ;
  do j=1 to 10;
    z=byte(97+floor(26*ranuni(0)));
    s=cats(s,z);
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Even with the `length` statement this still doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure why, but I've suggested a couple of alternatives.

Comment: You need to use `CATS()` and not `CAT()`.  Cat does not trim the arguments so the new character ends up in the 11th position and there is no room to store it back into a variable that has only 10 positions.